# flutter infinity scroll in both directions

Tags: flutter

I want to add an infinite image scroll in both directions. It should display an image in full width and be able to add images above and below without messing up the scroll position. I'm not sure if there is an easy way to implement that feature but to know how to create something like a canvas in HTML, where I could draw images to specific coordinates would be great. So I could just keep the offset and go into negative coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is CustomPaint in Flutter that works almost the same as HTML canvas.

It also allows you to place images at certain coordinates and then translate (move) the canvas as needed to certain coordinates.